# How to check if a fifo pipe is writable in PHP

Tags: php, pipe

I want to transfer messages from a PHP-based web-frontend to a backend service on a linux server.

I am sending the messages with `file_put_contents`. The interface works well when the backend service listens and reads the pipe created with `mkfifo mypipe`.

However, I would like to be prepared for a situation in which the backend service fails. In this case the user of the frontend should be be notified and given alternative options.

Currently, when the backend is not running, the frontend becomes unresponsive, because `file_put_contents` blocks.

I tried various things to solve the problem. This includes trying to open the pipe with `fopen` before `stream_context_create` and setting a timeout with `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);`

or

```
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array(
        'timeout' => 10
        )
    ));
    if(file_put_contents("mypipe",$data,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX,$context)==FALSE){
        error_log("Could not write to pipe.");
    }else{
        echo "Sent message";
    }
```

I also tried the PHP-function `is_writable("mypipe")`, but, as expected, it says yes independent of whether the receiver is listening.

How can I check if the pipe blocks and evade the situation that the frontend becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Do `fopen`, `stream_set_blocking`, `fwrite`, and `fclose` instead of using `file_put_contents`. When you do that, you'll be able to detect when it would block because `fwrite` will just return that it didn't write anything instead of blocking.

Comment: Will try. If the pipe is currently written by someone else, or currently not writable because it is full, will fwrite wait or return an error that allows me to distinguish between these cases?